# Inherit a new class method at runtime

Tags: ruby, inheritance, metaprogramming

In Ruby, `<ClassName>.constants` is useful to inspect classes:

```
> Numeric.constants(false)
=> [:KILOBYTE, :MEGABYTE, :GIGABYTE, :TERABYTE, :PETABYTE, :EXABYTE]
> Object.constants(false)
=> [:Object, :Module, ...]
```

This is defined in [`Module`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-constants):

```
> Object.method(:constants)
=> #<Method: Class(Module)#constants>
```

I'd like to add another method to print a hash with all the constants and their values. Here's the result so far:

```
def Module.constants_hash(inherit=true)
    self.constants(inherit).inject({}) do |hash, constant|
        hash[constant] = self::const_get(constant)
        hash
    end
end
```

This works for `Module` (although it has no constants, so the result is just an empty hash), but **it's not inherited**:

```
> Object.constants_hash(false)
NoMethodError: undefined method `constants_hash' for Object:Class
from (pry):117:in `<main>'
```

I can of course change the class name in the code to e.g. `Object` to make the call work, but is it possible to **make all the dependent modules inherit the new method** as well? In other words, **is it possible to add a method *at runtime* which is then inherited by classes which `require` the modified class?**

I'd rather not overload the original `Module.constants`, to avoid changing the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object` is an instance of type `Class`. `Class` class is inherited from `Module`. In order for `Object.constants_hash` to work, you need to define *instance* method of `Class` or `Module` classes:

```
class Module
  def constants_hash(inherit=true)
      self.constants(inherit).inject({}) do |hash, constant|
          hash[constant] = self::const_get(constant)
          hash
      end
  end
end
```

In you code you just add `constants_hash` to a *singleton class* of `Module` instance (of type `Class`), this is why you don't get expected result.

Comment: [This diagram](http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/RubyMethodLookupFlow.png) might help understand why this works.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck by declaring this method in a module, then mixing it in to each context as required:

```
module ConstantsHash
  def constants_hash(inherit = true)
    Hash[
      self.constants(inherit).collect do |constant|
        [ constant, const_get(constant) ]
      end
    ]
  end
end

Module.extend(ConstantsHash)
Object.extend(ConstantsHash)

puts Object.constants_hash.inspect
```

As a note, using `Hash[]` instead of `inject({ })` does seem to work better in cases like this.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference or simple explanation why `Hash[]` might be better than `inject({ })`?